# Trying to access Javascript files from WPF Control

Tags: c#, javascript, html, wpf-controls

Hi I'm trying to get a [JavaScript InfoVis SpaceTree](http://thejit.org/demos/) example to run on a WPF frame control.

To render the spacetree there are three required files:

1. excanvis.js
2. jit.js
3. example1.js

I have been able to get this to work on a WPF Frame control (and WebBrowser control) by creating a htm page and copying the contents of the three files directly into script tags in the html.

This results in a very large html file so I would like to reduce the size of the HTML file by referencing each of the three JavaScript files using the "src" attribure of the HTML script tag (e.g. `<Script src="excanvis.js"/><Script src="jit.js"/><Script src="example1.js"/>`).

Unfortunately, when I attempt to do this I get javascript errors. It seems that the WPF frame control cannot find the javascript content."

If anyone has any thoughts or ideas on a solution I would appreciate it a lot.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a path reference to the javascript files declared or defined anywhere..? try looking at this page for a starting point http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/f73bb9fa-3252-4c7e-b8e4-6cdad59fd825

Comment: I have added the three javascript files to the solution project and set the Copy Content to 'Copy Always' on the file properties.

Comment: Checkout that link it talks about WPF and javascript from a security standpoint.. have you looked at the solutions suggested on that link..?